# Preserve DOM changes when back button is used

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a HTML table with a delete button in each row. The delete button will make an AJAX call to the server to delete the record and on success the row will be removed from the table.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td><button class="delete-row" type="button">Delete Row</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('button.delete-row').click(function () {
        // Would delete the row with an AJAX request
        $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
    });
});
```

Here is a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/05vmz344/

This works fine except when a user follows a link to another page and then returns to this page using the browser's back button. The user is shown a stale version of the table with the deleted rows still visible (i.e. the DOM changes are lost).

I've looked at other similar questions on Stack Overflow and the suggestions include:

- Updating the URL hash (window.location.hash)
- Setting the Cache-Control header to force the browser to reload the page
- Using hidden input fields to keep track of the deleted rows, when the page loads delete rows according to the hidden fields
- Load the table using AJAX (instead of rendering it server-side)

However, none of these seem like good solutions to this problem. Are there any better solutions to this?

I seem to be at the point where a website becomes more like a desktop application and perhaps something like Apache Wicket or AngularJS would really come into their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options 1, 2, and 5 seems OK. I don't see how the 3rd option could work because the browser does not need to store changes in field values.

So unless you go the *single-page-web-application* way, like AngularJS, and avoid your navigation problem by not navigating to another page, you need to deal with the browse cache *problem*. The user could also have clicked a bookmark which is different but similar to the back button problem.

Additionally, not a very strong argument, but if you look at Stack Overflow you can see it uses `Cache-Control` and ajax requests.